# Why does explorer.exe use so much CPU?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, cpu, windows-explorer, sp2

The explorer.exe process on my Vista x64 has started using a lot of CPU recently.  Restarting the process typically solves the problem.

Is there a simple way to inspect the process to see where (threads, modules) the high CPU load is spent?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really an *easy* way of finding out what is causing the problem is, but the most likely cause are Explorer shell extensions (as well as several other items).

I would recommend you take a look at [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look under the explorer tab. However, do not press delete on anything, use this to identify problems (by unchecking boxes) and when you have found the problem - use the uninstaller for the application. Only press delete if the uninstaller fails to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to inspect the process and find out which threads/modules are using the processor.  Just double-click the process and sleect the **Threads** tab.

From there you can see which thread is using the processor.  You can also see the call stack of the thread to find out which module is hogging processor.